# Архитектура сервиса по распознаванию образов

Tags: архитектура, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание-образов

Вопрос к разработчикам проектов по распознаванию образов. Как лучше организовать архитектуру подобного сервиса?

Сейчас склоняюсь к решению использовать для работы с данными (а особенно для обучения) специализированные GPU-инстансы Amazon EC2 P2. На серверах установлено ПО только для работы искусственных нейронных сетей (Python, Anaconda, Keras, TensorFlow). В production-режиме сервер на вход принимает изображения с метаданными (как именно обработать изображение и какие данные вернуть), на выходе возвращает JSON-массив в зависимости от типа метаданных. Никакой особой логики там не хранится, вся аналитика происходит на серверах web-приложений.

Обучающие и тестовые выборки хранятся в отдельном кластере (обычные сервера с большим дисковым пространством). Туда же загружаются изображения из сети найденные собственными поисковыми ботами (через соцсети и поисковые системы).

Взаимодействие web-приложения с нейронной сетью осуществляется через API-запросы к GPU-серверам. Далее результат уже выдается на клиенты (аналогично с клиентов  все идет на web-приложение, а затем на обработку в нейронную сеть).

Теперь основные вопросы:

1. На каком участке вы проводите аналитику? (например, чтобы определить, что на фотографии на человеке надет синий мужской пиджак к нейронной сети выполняется каскад запросов "поиск мужчины"->"поиск пиджака"->"определение цвета пиджака". для получения более высокого качества ответа и снижения нагрузки на сеть каждый запрос выполняется отдельно при утвердительном предыдущем). Имеет ли смысл реализовывать все варианты поиска в рамках единой нейросети или лучше создать множество отдельных нейросетей, заточенных под достаточно простые задачи?
2. Как вы оптимизируете потребление ресурсов на этапах обучения и работы сети? Пока на уме только вариант с созданием специализированного GPU-кластера под обучение в рамках облачного хостинга и его периодическое включение по мере надобности (иначе дорого получается).

Comment: Вопрос закроют как общий, так как слишком много вопросов в одном. Необходимо разбить на несколько.

Comment: @edem что касается основного вопроса - он про построение архитектуры в целом. немного подправил, чтобы был понятнее главный смысл

Comment: И нейронные сети - это всё не так продуктивно, как кажется. Прощё написать алгоритм, чем добиваться такого-же алгоритма, обучая сеть, мало того результат будет гораздо производительнее. Делал распознавание изображений на сегментации (без ИНС), работало на обычном сервере. Задача была такая - на одном большом изображении 5 предметов(повёрнутые, искажённые, наклонённые), база предметов фиксированная - 2к картинок. Требовалось определить - каких категорий предметов на картинке больше всего. И работало это с вероятностью 60%

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр при анализе текстовых данных соглашусь, но при анализе графических все же без нейронных сетей сложно. достаточно простые реализации ИНС позволяют выходить на 90-95% верных ответов (по нормальным, не "убитым" фото, при обучении по выборке 1000-2000 картинок с аугментацией).

Comment: @Dmitry Maslennikov да, сегодня это может быть проще, если составить программу автообучение ИНС. Но, у нейросетей очень туго с поворотами картинки - в моей задаче был произвольный угол поворота: и самое печальное в этом - сама проблема подхода скармливания картинок нейросети. Чтобы нейросеть нормально работала с углами - растровую графику нужно сначала худо-бедно преобразовать в векторную, и кормить уже векторные данные. Но если вы это сделали - то в распознавании уже тоже можно обойтись без ИНС. Могу заблуждаться, т.к. работал с этим в 2012 году..

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр в той или иной степени это все так и работает. те же библиотеки Curve CV или Tensorflow оперируют векторными параметрами. с поворотами да, есть такое дело (даже при векторном анализе), но вижу выход в аугментации исходных фотографий под разные углы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваши вопросы говорят о том что, вы не осознаете всей сложности проблемы поиска *мужчины* на фото, не говоря уж о поиске пиджака. Хотя бы найти объект произвольного размера на фото по меркам на конец 2017 года - [это уже передний край науки](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN).

Сначала начните с простого. Попытайтесь хотя бы в общих чертах решить вашу проблему, о которой ни слова в вопросе. Арендуете ли вы для этого один сервер, или купите подходящую видеокарту - дело второе. Можно и без видеокарт. Как только вы поймете что для радикального уменьшения ошибки обучения вам нужны годы на ваших мощностях, тогда можно будет говорить об аренде кластера. И тогда вы можете обратиться к документации на TensorFlow чтобы [узнать как конкретно решаются подобные проблемы](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).